# Using a WCF callback (duplex) service synchronously

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, callback, duplex, synchronous

I have an existing WCF service that I now need to have consume an external WCF callback (aka duplex) service. The duplex service is by its nature asynchronous and yet I need to keep my original WCF service synchronous. Is there a well known pattern to do this? What are the most important pitfalls I need to watch out for?

My current intention is to invoke the duplex service and then wait for a ManualResetEvent to be raised. When the callback is called by the duplex, it would reset the event and make the waiting operation resume and complete its work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I'd go this way too. Pay attention to how you control these events' lifetime. Seems like you'll need to pass some id to the duplex service so that, when callback arrives, this id could be resolved into the original `ManualResetEvent`.

Comment: Indeed. Each ManualResetEvent will be associated with a unique identifier. When that identifier is returned via the callback, the associated MRE is reset.